# Turning foreach loops to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there anyway to write turn this for each loop into Linq expression:

```
private List<string> datasetItemset;
Dictionary<string, int> itemsetScanning = new Dictionary<string, int>();
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
foreach (string transaction in this.datasetItemset)
{
    string[] items = transaction.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    foreach (string item in items)
        if (!itemList.Contains(item))
        {
            itemList.Add(item);
            itemsetScanning.Add(item, 0);
        }
}
```

My next question is that , does using linq expressions instead of foreach loop speed up the performance of the program, I'm kind of new to this linq.

Update: Using too many foreach loop is slowing down my program.

Comment: not sure linq can increase the speed. But few lines

Comment: Linq is in fact [much slower](http://ox.no/posts/linq-vs-loop-a-performance-test) than non-linq code

Comment: I'm using too many foreach loops and they are really slowing down my program so I'm looking for a more efficient way to make it faster

Comment: If you really want to use LINQ, you can shorten it to this: `foreach (var item in items.Where(item => !itemList.Contains(item)))`

Comment: Linq is for esthetics, ease of use, and readability, it all goes into IL code at one point or another. Look for other places to increase performance, if its an issue.

Comment: @Tyrsius: 1) That's a beta.  2) It depends what you're doing; `ToArray()` is very slow and usually unnecessary.  3) He's measuring wrongly.

Comment: @Jay: You're forgetting about deferred execution; LINQ can be much faster than simple loops for certain operations.

Comment: @Tyrsius Not only that, but currently it stands at only 7x better (with his flawed measuring technique). So really, the difference is pretty much nil right now.

Comment: @SLaks I've heard this [same conclusion](http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html) in [several places](http://www.anujvarma.com/linq-versus-loopingperformance/). Do you have anything demonstrating otherwise?

Comment: @Tyrsius It's all about writing the LINQ correctly.  In general, it will always be slower than a hand-tuned loop, but the difference is often extremely small.  Mostly, it's slower if used heavily in tight loops, as you are often creating a bit more allocations with LINQ, which can cause more GC pressure - the actual statements are typically very similar to the speed of loops, though.

Comment: @Tyrsius - that test was very shallow, and IMHO didn't give a good representation of where linq excels, example - `list.Intersect(otherlist).Where(something).Select(aValue).ToList()`, I'd imagine a good test on something like that would be a fairer test

Comment: @Sayse I'd be interested in seeing such a test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does using linq expressions instead of foreach loop speed up the performance of the program, I'm kind of new to this linq.

No.  Internally, LINQ will still typically perform the same number of iterations, so in general, it won't speed things up.  Written properly, LINQ will perform very similarly to the looping.

It is very useful to make the intent more clear, which in turn can sometimes make it simpler to optimize and short curcuit.  That being said, those same optimizations can be done on loops just as easily.

> Is there anyway to write turn this for each loop into Linq expression:

Yes.  This could be done via:

```
foreach(var item in this.datasetItemset
   .SelectMany(transaction => transaction.Split(' '))
   .Distinct())
{
    itemList.Add(item);
    itemsetScanning.Add(item, 0);
}
```

Note that the inner body/loop is left as a `foreach` loop, on purpose, in this case, as it's performing side effects.

Given that it appears you're building list and a set, you could use:

```
var itemList = this.datasetItemset.SelectMany(transaction => transaction.Split(' ')).ToList();
var uniqueSet = new HashSet<string>(itemList); // Build the set from the list
```

This would provide you a set of unique values (as a `HashSet<string>`) as well as the list of values.  If you just need a unique list of values, you can use `Distinct` to build it directly:

```
 var uniqueItemList = this.datasetItemset
                          .SelectMany(transaction => transaction.Split(' '))
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList();
```

If you need the dictionary, then it's merely taking these results:

```
var itemsetScanning = uniqueItemList.ToDictionary(i => i, i => 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much reed I think I got my answer:).

Comment: This does not guarantee uniqueness.  Use a HashSet or `.Distinct()`.

Comment: I don't think the result will be the same.

Comment: @SLaks This was trying to match the original code - have edited to include something to build a list + hashset directly, though.

Comment: I have to do something very similar to this, but instead of populating a list with the selected items, I have to populate a list of objects that take the selected item as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @James Just pass through a .Select and construct your items.

Answer (score 1):

here is ugly linq

```
foreach (var item in this.datasetItemset
    .Select(transaction => transaction.Split(new char[] { ' ' }))
    .SelectMany(items => items
        .Where(item => !itemList.Contains(item))))
    {
        itemList.Add(item);
        itemsetScanning.Add(item, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> itemList = this.datasetItemset
    .SelectMany(item => item.Split(' '))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var itemsetScanning = itemList.ToDictionary(e => e, _ => 0);
```

Regarding performance, Linq will be slower than a carefully-crafted specific solution, but it is usually quick enough. If performance is an issue for you, you should probably avoid it (after profiling).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Ok well you can create `itemList` eagerly

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write out that code:

```
var itemList = datasetItemset.SelectMany(transaction => transaction.Split(' '))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
var itemsetScanning = itemList.ToDictionary(transaction => transaction,
    transaction => 0);
```

This is the more idiomatic LINQ way of addressing the problem.

The nested foreach generally maps to a `SelectMany` call, and rather than checking if the item already exists you can use `Distinct`, which not only semantically represents what you're trying to do, but will be noticeably more efficient (as you're avoiding repeated linear searches through a list; you could use a `HashSet` to more efficiently search in a non-LINQ solution if you wanted).  Rather than adding the items to collections, you can instead convert each sequence directly into a collection using `ToList` and `ToDictionary`, to avoid explicitly using a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do the same using LINQ:

```
var itemList = this.datasetItems
                   .SelectMany(x => x.split(' '))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();

var itemssetScanning = itemList.ToDictionary(x => x, x => 0);
```

However, there still are `foreach` loops hidden inside `SelectMany`, `Distinct`, `ToList` and `ToDictionary` methods. **There is no magic here!** Additional delegates calls makes it slower then custom loops.

Comment: The overhead of the delegates isn't too significant.  Also note that the implementation of `Distinct` is dramatically better than the OP's algorithm, which will result in a significant performance improvement, most likely more so than the overhead of the delegates if there is enough data for performance to matter to begin with.

Comment: @Servy You're right. `HashSet` used by `Distinct` is much better then `Contains`, so it would be better then his current solution.  @AustinSalonen He's already edited his answer. I criticize the previous version.